# MIPS: Midpoint Circle Algorithm

Tags: assembly, bitmap, mips32, mars-simulator

I'm trying to draw a circle in the bitmap using MARS. I've converted the c formula from Wikipedia, however the result I'm getting is wrong. I'm thinking there's an error with my conversion but I can't for the life of me figure out what it is.

```
#Procedure: drawCircle:
#Draw a circle in the center of the input pixel (This will be implemented using the 
#midpoint circle algorithm from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_circle_algorithm
#a0 = x0
#a1 = y0
#a2 = color
#a3 = radius
drawCircle:
    #MAKE ROOM ON STACK
    addi        $sp, $sp, -20       #Make room on stack for 1 words
    sw      $ra, 0($sp)     #Store $ra on element 0 of stack
    sw      $a0, 4($sp)     #Store $a0 on element 1 of stack
    sw      $a1, 8($sp)     #Store $a1 on element 2 of stack
    sw      $a2, 12($sp)        #Store $a1 on element 3 of stack
    sw      $a3, 16($sp)        #Store $a1 on element 4 of stack

    #VARIABLES
    move        $t0, $a0            #x0
    move        $t1, $a1            #y0
    move        $t2, $a3            #radius
    addi        $t3, $t2, -1            #x
    li      $t4, 0              #y
    li      $t5, 1              #dx
    li      $t6, 1              #dy
    li      $t7, 0              #Err

    #CALCULATE ERR (dx - (radius << 1))
    sll         $t8, $t2, 1         #Bitshift radius left 1 
    subu        $t7, $t5, $t8           #Subtract dx - shifted radius 

    #While(x >= y)
    circleLoop:
    blt         $t3, $t4, skipCircleLoop    #If x < y, skip circleLoop

    #Draw Dot (x0 + x, y0 + y)
    addu        $a0, $t0, $t3
    addu        $a1, $t1, $t4
    lw          $a2, 12($sp)
    jal         drawDot             #Jump to drawDot

        #Draw Dot (x0 + y, y0 + x)
        addu        $a0, $t0, $t4
        addu        $a1, $t1, $t3
        lw      $a2, 12($sp)
        jal     drawDot             #Jump to drawDot

        #Draw Dot (x0 - y, y0 + x)
        subu        $a0, $t0, $t4
        addu        $a1, $t1, $t3
        lw      $a2, 12($sp)
        jal     drawDot             #Jump to drawDot

        #Draw Dot (x0 - x, y0 + y)
        subu        $a0, $t0, $t3
        addu        $a1, $t1, $t4
        lw      $a2, 12($sp)
        jal     drawDot             #Jump to drawDot

        #Draw Dot (x0 - x, y0 - y)
        subu        $a0, $t0, $t3
        subu        $a1, $t1, $t4
        lw      $a2, 12($sp)
        jal     drawDot             #Jump to drawDot

        #Draw Dot (x0 - y, y0 - x)
        subu        $a0, $t0, $t4
        subu        $a1, $t1, $t3
        lw      $a2, 12($sp)
        jal     drawDot             #Jump to drawDot

        #Draw Dot (x0 + y, y0 - x)
        addu        $a0, $t0, $t4
        subu        $a1, $t1, $t3
        lw      $a2, 12($sp)
        jal     drawDot             #Jump to drawDot

        #Draw Dot (x0 + x, y0 - y)
        addu        $a0, $t0, $t3
        subu        $a1, $t1, $t4
        lw      $a2, 12($sp)
        jal     drawDot             #Jump to drawDot

    #If (err <= 0)
    bgtz        $t7, doElse
    addi        $t4, $t4, 1     #y++
    addu        $t7, $t7, $t6       #err += dy
    addi        $t6, $t6, 2     #dy += 2
    j       circleContinue      #Skip else stmt

    #Else If (err > 0)
    doElse:
    addi        $t3, $t3, -1        #x--
    addi        $t5, $t5, 2     #dx += 2
    sll     $t8, $t2, 1     #Bitshift radius left 1 
    subu        $t9, $t5, $t8       #Subtract dx - shifted radius 
    addu        $t7, $t7, $t9       #err += $t9

    circleContinue:
    #LOOP
    j       circleLoop

    #CONTINUE
    skipCircleLoop:     

    #RESTORE $RA
    lw      $ra, 0($sp)     #Restore $ra from stack
    addi        $sp, $sp, 20        #Readjust stack
```

None of the procedures I call change any t-registers. The result I get with the following values: x = 10 y = 10 color = 5 radius = 10

[image]

Comment: Have you single-stepped through your code in the debugger to look for where register values aren't what you expect?

Comment: @PeterCordes Yes, I'm still in the process of doing it now because there are a lot of values. So far nothing has caught my eye. I just want to make sure I've made no obvious mistakes with the conversion. One thing that I've noticed is that the first and second drawDots are far apart which doesn't seem correct.

Comment: Here's something strange, when the coordinates for the first and second dots are drawn, they are 10, 19 and 19, 10 respectively. When they are drawn, one is drawn on the left half of the bitmap while the other is drawn on the right half.

Comment: where is `drawDot` code? ... ah, you figured it out meanwhile... yes, the size of the bitmap did look like good candidate, because calculating target address with wrong width size will make y coordinate to "wrap" around to all places in predictable way (like drawing into 512x512 when you expect 256x256 will make every other line positioned in the right half of picture, while odd lines are on left and the total picture is half of desired size, using 512x128 area only)

Answer (score 0):

I think I've figured it out. The problem wasn't the conversion but the size of the bitmap. It seems that when the bitmap is to small, the circle ends up wrapping around.